# How to change access level of inherited methods in Scala

Tags: scala

I am extending an existing library (lets call it `Lib`) that I cannot modify directly.

Is there any way to make some methods from `Lib` private so that they cannot be accessed outside of subclasses?

For example if I have:

```
class A extends Lib {
    def fun(i: int) = someLibFunction(i) //someLibFunction is inherited from Lib
}
```

how can I make `someLibFunction` private in A, despite it being public/protected in Lib?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This would break the basic foundation of object-oriented programming - that you can use subclass everywhere where super class was expected (polymorphism).

If it was allowed to narrow down the visibility of a method (e.g. from `public` to `private`) client code receiving an instance of `Lib` would not be allowed to receive `A extends Lib`. Client code expects `someLibFunction()` to be accessible and subclass cannot change that contract.

That being said neither Scala nor any object-oriented language is allowed to narrow down the visibility of any method when subclassing. Note that widening the visibility (e.g. from `protected` to `public` is perfectly possible).

In other words you are not **extending** an existing API (library). You are creating a completely different API (library) that has a different contract.

Final example: you have a `Vehicle` class that has a `capacity()` and can `drive()`. `Car` can extend `Vehicle` by adding some new capabilities like `refuel()`. But `Container` cannot extend `Vehicle` and hide driving capability. `Container` can *contain* `Vehicle` (or vice-versa), also `Container` and `Vehicle` might have common parent like `CanHoldCargo`.

Comment: And what if I want to do the opposite. I.e., to turn public an inherited private or protected? Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 0):

When you're using a 3rd party library, sometimes it's a good idea to wrap it in a single point in your code.

This will make it easier to manage possible future changes in that 3rd party software (if you choose to move up with the versions).

This has been a good practice since before Scala.

Once you're wrapping your 3rd party library, you can easily occlude the parts of its API you don't want to access from your own code (just don't give them a wrapper method/class...).